# scheme/racket super-type and accessing struct properties

Tags: scheme, racket

How do i access the layer property of r, and where does the 1 go? And i can only access the 2 and 3 using point-x and point-y, even though it's a common-value struct..

```
#lang racket

(define (object-constructor super-type layer)
  (struct commmon-value(layer)
    #:super super-type
    #:transparent
    #:property prop:procedure (lambda (self)
                                           layer))
  comm)

(struct point (x y) 
  #:transparent
  #:property prop:procedure (lambda (self)
                                      x y)))

(define r ((object-constructor struct:point 1) 2 3 4))
(point-x r)
(point-y r)
r
> (comm 2 3 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang racket

(struct layer (common) 
  #:transparent
  #:property prop:procedure (lambda (self) (layer-common self)))

(struct point layer (x y) 
  #:transparent
  #:property prop:procedure (lambda (self) (layer-common self)))

(define r (point 1 2 3))
(match-define (point c x y) r)

(r)
c
x 
y
```

The ouput is:

```
1
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks for informing me about match-define, but it doesn't really answer my original question because i want to know what happened to the missing variables.

Comment: There is no common-value-x since not all common-value structs have an x. Your point struct does, so point-x exists.

Comment: Then how do i access layer?

Comment: All common values have a layer, so you use common-value-layer.

Comment: That's what i tried! but i get -> common-value-layer: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition

Comment: Move (struct commmon-value(layer) ...) outside the definition of object-constructor. If you place it in the body, you can only use common-value-layer inside the body of object-constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66482/discussion-between-krc-and-soegaard).